# Pass a user entered variable to php before POST?

Tags: php, html, realex-payments-api

I have a page that contains a form. This page also has a PHP script to set some variables.
These variables are then submitted as hidden values when the user clicks submit.

I have a requirement to take a users entered value (amount) and then set that as a variable inside the PHP , then post the form. Is this possible ?

I cannot just sent the form submitted value as it must go through a MD5 hash first in the PHP script. This is a requirment for Realex creditcard payments.

I was thinking this might be possible with JavaScript?

EDIT

Just to clarify , the page has PHP (simplified here for example)

```
<?php
$amount ="";
$tmp = "$timestamp.$merchantid.$orderid.$amount.$curr";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
$tmp = "$md5hash.$secret";
$md5hash = md5($tmp);
?>
```

All of the above variables are pre-defined and dont change, however the amount is dependant on what the customer enters.

The form is on the same page as the above , so when the customer enters a value , then hit submit ... this along with the md5 hash above is sent.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="donate_amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="<?=$amount?>
</form>
```

but Im not sure how to do this dynamically before posting.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want encryption to take place before the information is sent over the network? If so, javascript is definitely the right direction.

Comment: Would you have an example by any chance ? Ive used java to pass variables to another page but never to the same page before then submitting

Comment: I suggest to take a look on jQuery for your problem, it is easier to write effcient Javascript with http://jquery.com/

Comment: You should not use a JavaScript solution. JavaScript should only be used for noncritical enhancements and not for critical parts like this because it could have been turned of by the user in the browser or by e.g. NoScript.

Comment: @t.niese also the data can be manipulated...

Comment: @Bondye yes you are right. removed the part in the braces.

Comment: You use sessions for such purposes. Any nonsense like JS solutions is extremely insecure.

Comment: MD5 implementation in js http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm getting this correctly without seeing code, but from what I got from it what I think you want to to is save whatever it is to a session.

so if its coming from input

```
$_SESSION['derp'] = Hash::howeveryouhash($_POST['derp'])
```

or if hash happens after input is gotten just save the hashed input to a session?

I'm not sure if this what you meant, but if it is, be sure sure to reference the php manual to insure proper use of $_SESSION!

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the final amount before you create the hidden form Gary. There's no point creating the hash without it.

You should ask the user for the amount they wish to donate on the previous page. Then you can present a final "Donation Overview" page containing the hidden form, and the "Proceed to Payment" button.

Whatever you end up implementing, don't put the Realex shared secret in the javascript on the page! This must be kept secured on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

How about doing this:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" onchange="ajaxFunction(this)" value="" />
```

Then when the input field changes the function ajaxFunction calls a PHP script sending the value. In the PHP script you can store the value in $_SESSION['amount'] for later use.

```
function ajaxFunction(obj) {
   $.post("store_amount.php", { amount: $(obj).val() } );
}
```

Requires jQuery.

Comment: This solution would work for the OP - use the `onChange` event for the amount field to send an Ajax request to the server to compute a new hash and then update the `SHA1HASH` field - but it is very over-engineered and will probably cause more trouble than it's worth.